# AdditionalPropertiesAllowed doesn't work Swashbuckle

Tags: .net, swagger, swashbuckle, json-schema-validator, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) version 6.2.3
I have a POST endpoint with [FromBody] dto and want to block any additional properties on model.
In order to achieve this using `AdditionalPropertiesAllowed = false` on OpenApiSchema.

Here's generated schema.

```
"Dto": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "attachments": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AttachmentDto"
            },
            "nullable": true
          },
          "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EditItemsDto"
            },
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
```

I expect getting error when passing this body to my POST endpoint

```
{
  "attachments": [
    {
      "path": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "size": 0
    }
  ],
  "item": [
    {
      "itemCode": "string",
    }
  ],
  "notAllowedProp" : "test"
}
```

But there's no any error.

I added EnableValidator() but it didn't help

**AddSwaggerGen**

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = "v1",
                    Title = "Service",
                    Description = ApiDocumentation.GetErrorDescriptions()
                });
                var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "cm.Service.xml");
                c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
                c.AddFluentValidationRules();
                c.DocumentFilter<AdditionalPropertiesDocumentFilter>();
            });
```

Document filter is setting `AdditionalPropertiesAllowed = false`

**UseSwaggerUI**

```
app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
                c.EnableValidator();
            });
```